# EntityManagerFactory is not been injected - JPA

Tags: servlets, jpa

I'm a begginer with JPA, and I'm having problems when I use @PersistenceUnit in a servlet. EntityManagerFactory is not being injected, and I don't know why.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{   

  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf = null; 

  public MyServlet ()
  {
    super();        
  }

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(config);
  }


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Writer w = response.getWriter();
    w.append("HELLO HELLO");
    w.close();
  }

}
```

I've configured the persistence.xml file (inside META-INF directory) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="MiddlewareExpedElectrModel" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>     
    <non-jta-data-source>java:/OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.ieci.mugeju.middleware.model.entities.FechaUltimaSolicitudProcesada</class>
    <properties>         
     <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
     <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>         
  </properties>     
</persistence-unit>
```

Why is not the EntityManagerFactory being injected?

I'm working with Jboss 4.2.3, and I have also configured a datasource with a oracle-ds.xml file.

**UPDATE:**

If I try to get the EntityManagerFactory programatically, it works well:

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MiddlewareExpedElectrModel");
```

But I would like to get a EntityManagerFactory instance via injection.
Thanks!

Comment: Anybody can help me? :(

Comment: Have you tried with `@PersistenceContext(unitName="MiddlewareExpedElectrModel", name="persistence/em")` above `public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {` ?

Comment: No, I haven't try it. But I think that I read that @PersistenceContext must not be used in a HttpServlet.

Comment: PersistenceContext should not be used in a servlet because it is not thread-safe and since the servlets are not thread-safe you may have a problem (in comparison you can inject a PersistenceContext in a EJB because a EJB instance calls are serialized).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
//this is thread-safe
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="MiddlewareExpedElectrModel")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

As far as I know, methods in EntityManager interface are not thread-safe, and may not be shared among multiple concurrent requests. Therefore, do not inject EntityManager into a servlet instance variable.

this is not thread-safe, and avoid it

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="MiddlewareExpedElectrModel")
private EntityManager em;
```

You can still inject EntityManager at the servlet class type level, and look it up when needed during request processing.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="MiddlewareExpedElectrModel", name="persistence/em")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(
HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
  EntityManager em =
   (EntityManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/em");
  } catch (NamingException ex) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried it as you told me, using the 'unitName' attribute, but it doesn't work again. The emf instance is always null, is not being injected. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried without `null` ? `private EntityManagerFactory emf;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my application on glassfish server.
The entitymanager factory was always null until I removed the servlet declaration from web.xml and I used annotation to declare the servlet.

```
@WebServlet("/GetRevisioniServlet")  // <-- this annotation solved all my problems
public class GetRevisioniServlet extends HttpServlet {

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "clerpPU")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        EntityManager em = null;
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); 
        .....
    }
 }
```